# Can you still test iPhone applications on an iPhone without a cell carrier?

Tags: ios, iphone, cellular-network

I'm about to start doing some iPhone application development and it's important to me to be able to test my applications on actual devices before I put them on the marketplace. However, I am planning on switching from AT&T to Verizon soon due largely to the cost of my current plan.

If I discontinue my AT&T service but keep my iPhone 3G hardware, will there be anything that prevents me from testing my applications on this iPhone even though it doesn't have any service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is one catch to the iPhone: it needs a valid SIM card (though maybe not current service) in order to activate it after an upgrade or restore.

Comment: So I should probably upgrade to iOS 4.0 before I discontinue my service then?

Comment: Correct. But you won't be able to upgrade or restore in the future to iOS5 etc. Otherwise, Wifi will work fine. Unrelated, I'm surprised the Verizon plan will be cheaper, they all seem to be the same price.

Comment: The Verizon data plans are actually a lot higher than I thought and are pretty similar to AT&T - the only difference is that the data plan is still unlimited with Verizon.

Answer (score 0):

No. It will be similar to developing on an iPod touch.